# A bus error that occurs when mmap memory is used with memcpy

Tags: linux, mmap, memcpy, device-driver, bus-error

Recently, when I make a Linux device driver and memcpy memory obtained with mmap, the Linux kernel has a bus error and I ask questions.

Here's the code that caused the problem

```c
typedef struct buffer_t {
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned long phys_addr;
    unsigned long base;
    unsigned long virt_addr;
} buffer_t;

int main(void)
{
  buffer_t vdb;
  Uint8 *buf = 0;
  int32 len = 0;

  vdi->vpu_fd = open(DEVICE_NAME, O_RDWR);
  len = 100;


  buf = (Uint8*)malloc(len);

  vdb.virt_addr = (unsigned long)mmap(NULL, vdb.size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, vdi->vpu_fd, vdb.phys_addr);

  memcpy(data, (const char *)(vdb.virt_addr), len);
}
```

When executing the above code, an Bus error occurs while performing memcpy.

It's not impossible to write values for the address of the data and the address of vdb.virt_addr.

like this.

The code below does not have a bus error.

```c
  for( j = 0 ; j < len ; j++)
  {
    *(data+j) = *(((unsigned char*)(vdb.virt_addr))+j);
  }
```

And if the memcpy size is a multiple of 8 as shown below, it works (although the rest is thrown away)

The code below does not have a bus error.

```c
int r_len = (len/8)*8;
memcpy(data, (const char *)(vdb.virt_addr), r_len);
```

Has anyone experienced this or knows any solutions?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. Among other things, you need to tell us the values of `DEVICE_NAME` and `vdb.phys_addr`.

Comment: Did you write the device driver in question yourself? If you did, then the bug is almost certainly in its code that you didn't post, and not in the userspace code that you posted.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica 
Did you write the device driver in question yourself? -> yes, DEVICE_NAME is the name of the device driver I wrote myself. like /dev/myddevice

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica vdb.phys_addr is the physical address of the DRAM of the target I want to run.

Comment: Neither `vdb.size` nor `vdb.phys_addr` are initialised so they have indeterminate values.